# Meteor Block Helper that acts like a template

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Here's what I want, a custom block helper that can act like a template, monitoring for it's own events etc. The html would look like this:

```html
{{#expandable}}
    {{#if expanded}}
        Content!!!
        <div id="toggle-area"></div>
    {{else}}
        <div id="toggle-area"></div>
    {{/if}}
{{/expandable}}
```

And here's some javascript I have put together. This would work if I just declared the above as a template, but I want it to apply to whatever input is given to that `expandable` block helper.

```js
Template.expandableView.created = function() {
    this.data._isExpanded = false;
    this.data._isExpandedDep = new Deps.Dependency();
}
Template.expandableView.events({
    'click .toggle-area': function(e, t) {
        t.data._isExpanded = !t.data._isExpanded;
        t.data._isExpandedDep.changed();
    }
});
Template.expandableView.expanded = function() {
    this._isExpandedDep.depend();
    return this._isExpanded;
};
```

I know I can declare block helpers with syntax like this:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('expandable', function() {
    var contents = options.fn(this);
    // boring block helper that unconditionally returns the content
    return contents;
});
```

But that wouldn't have the template behavior.

Thanks in advance! This might not be really possible with the current Meteor implementation.

## Update

The implementation given by HubertOG is super cool, but the `expanded` helper isn't accessible from *within* the `content` below:

```html
<template name="expandableView">
    {{expanded}} <!-- this works correctly -->
    {{content}}
</template>

<!-- in an appropriate 'home' template -->
{{#expandable}}
    {{expanded}} <!-- this doesn't work correctly. Expanded is undefined. -->
    <button class="toggle-thing">Toggle</button>
    {{#if expanded}}
        Content is showing!
    {{else}}
        Nope....
    {{/if}}
{{/expandable}}
```

In the actual block helper, `expanded` is undefined, since the real thing is a level up in the context. I tried things like `{{../expanded}}` and `{{this.expanded}}`, but to no avail.

Strangely, the event handler is correctly wired up.... it fires when I click that button, but the `expanded` helper is simply never called from within the `content`, so even `console.log()` calls are never fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor's new [Blaze template engine](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#new-pattern-for-defining-custom-block-helpers) solves this problem quite nicely.

Here's an excerpt from the Blaze docs showing how they can be used.

> Definition:
>
> ```
> <template name="ifEven">
>   {{#if isEven value}}
>     {{> UI.contentBlock}}
>   {{else}}
>     {{> UI.elseBlock}}
>   {{/if}}
> </template>
>
> Template.ifEven.isEven = function (value) {
>   return (value % 2) === 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> {{#ifEven value=2}}
>   2 is even
> {{else}}
>   2 is odd
> {{/ifEven}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by making a helper that returns a template, and passing the helper options as a data to that template.

First, make your helper template:

```
<template name="helperTemplate">
  <div class="this-is-a-helper-box">
    <p>I'm a helper!</p>
    {{helperContents}}
  </div>
</template>
```

This will work as a typical template, i.e. it can respond to events:

```
Template.helperTemplate.events({
  'click .click-me': function(e, t) {
    alert('CLICK!');
  },
});
```

Finally, make a helper that will return this template.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('blockHelper', function(options) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template.helperTemplate({
    helperContents: new Handlebars.SafeString(options.fn(this)),
  }));
});
```

The helper options are passed as a `helperContents` param inside the template data. We used that param in the template to display the contents. Notice also that you need to wrap the returned HTML code in `Handlebars.SafeString`, both in the case of the template helper and its data.

Then you can use it just as intended:

```
<template name="example">

  {{#blockHelper}}
    Blah blah blah
    <div class="click-me">CLICK</div>
  {{/blockHelper}}

</template>
```

Comment: Hey, please take a look at my edit. It seems things weren't as simple as they first appeared :/